# set background of the body to a randomized google image

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-search-api

As you can see I have this code, I want to run a search for the `keyword` that I select, in this case it being "mountains".

What this code does is -> it searches for the image of the given `keyword` -> then it checks for a random image in the data it receives -> then it sets the background image to the random image.

But as I run this code, it doesn't seem to give me the wanted result.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var keyword = "mountains";

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
        {
            tags: keyword,
            tagmode: "any",
            format: "json"
        },
        function(data) {
            var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.items.length);

            var image_src = data.items[rnd]['media']['m'].replace("_m", "_b");

            $('body').css('background-image', "url('" + image_src + "')");

        });

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

So my question is: can I change the `api.flickr.com` to a google search api, so my image search results get improved and set to the background as mentioned?

And if, then how?

Already thanks for your support!

Comment: You could use https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

Comment: Yes, but how would I implement this, so it sets the searched randomized image result as background @Gerardo? I am quite new to the google search api.

Comment: Right, let me write an example...

Comment: When Google detects programmatical attempts to fetch search results it blocks the IP and displays a captcha before any results page. Don't go there.

Comment: Then how would you set a randomized background that searches on the `keyword` you want with optimized results @andreigheorghiu?

Comment: I'm under the impression your question should be asked at Google. AFAIK, you do not have the right to display those images, unless Google or the image owners give you express permission to do so.

Comment: @KingReload In the answer you can also get an API key from here https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview just go to the Prerequisites - API Key section and click "Get a key"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you requested

[Example](http://jsbin.com/gojerifana/1/edit?js,output)

But before running this snippet, first create an API key on Google for this and a custom search engine which you will need it's ID. Also after you created a custom engine you need to enable the "Image search" option.

Replace `var API_KEY = "your_api_key"` with the key provided by Google

and `var ENGINE_ID = "your_engine_id"` also with the id provided by Google.

Here are the links:

API console

[Google API console](https://console.developers.google.com/project)

Custom Search Engine

https://cse.google.com/all

Comment: thanks! but my browser gets a `GET 400()` error from jquery.min.js?

Comment: after I put in the ajax jquery it crashes on `jquery.js:9664`

Comment: Yes you did, I just followed the tutorial from back to forward again and the only thing I missed was that the `document.ready` of jquery was not over the code yet. Plus I can only send 100 queries a day as limit of google, but for the rest it works perfectly ✌ thanks a lot

Comment: @KingReload Great! sorry if I wasn't clear, I'm not really a good english speaker but I'm glad it helped.

Comment: About the query limits yeah I forgot to mention that, but it's the same with all Google API's, you need to pay. If you need good quality pictures as background there's also Unsplash: https://unsplash.com/developers they don't have as much images as Yahoo! or Google but are pretty good.

Comment: I'll look into it! :) but I'm already gratefull for helping me out towards this point!